# How do I convert this enum to an NS_ENUM?

Tags: objective-c, enums, 32bit-64bit

I've been working on converting Objective-C code to use `NS` types so we can more easily switch between 32- and 64-bit. Most of the `enum`s I've run into look like this:

```
typedef enum {
    ValueA = 0,
    ValueB,
    ...
    ValueN,
} NameOfEnum;
```

and so I simply replace `typedef enum` with `typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, NameOfEnum)`, remove the trailing NameOfEnum, and move on, making code that looks like this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, NameOfEnum) {
    ValueA = 0,
    ValueB,
    ...
    ValueN,
};
```

However, one special library formats its enums like such:

```
enum NameOfEnum
{
    ValueA = 0,
    ValueB,
    ...
    ValueN,
};
typedef enum NameOfEnum NameOfEnum;
```

**How do I convert this?** Intuitively I want to replace `enum NameOfEnum` with my standard `typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, NameOfEnum)` and just delete that last line altogether. **Is that the right thing to do, or will that possibly break something else far along in this extensive library?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. The last one first creates an enum and then creates a type with the same name.

Comment: Thanks! And will this change create any foreseeable problems?

Comment: It is the same thing. In early "C" the last example was common.